# File dialog is crashing, where do I report the bug?

Tags: bug-reporting

Whenever I try to open a file, for example within gedit, an application crashes immediately. 
The same happens with other apps. If it does matter, I'm connecting to ubuntu remotely via VNC.
Here is the stacktrace:

```
 *** glibc detected *** gedit: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x000000000130b8e0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x774b6)[0x7fb39b50f4b6]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7b55f)[0x7fb39b51355f]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x6e)[0x7fb39b51438e]
/usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0(+0x1724b)[0x7fb3982a324b]
/usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0(pixman_image_create_solid_fill+0x9)[0x7fb3982c48b9]
/usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0(pixman_image_fill_boxes+0x23a)[0x7fb3982be63a]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14

...

7fb38ab43000-7fb38ad42000 ---p 000e8000 09:02 133465                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
7fb38ad42000-7fb38ad4a000 r--p 000e7000 09:02 133465                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
7fb38ad4a000-7fb38ad4c000 rw-p 000ef000 09:02 133465                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
7fb38ad4c000-7fb38ad61000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb38ad61000-7fb38ad6c000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 8257554                    /usr/lib/enchant/libenchant_ispell.so
7fb38ad6c000-7fb38af6c000 ---p 0000b000 09:02 8257554                    /usr/lib/enchant/libenchant_ispell.so
7fb38af6c000-7fb38af6d000 r--p 0000b000 09:02 8257554                    /usr/lib/enchant/libenchant_ispell.so
7fb38af6d000-7fb38af6e000 rw-p 0000c000 09:02 8257554                    /usr/lib/enchant/libenchant_ispell.so
7fb38af6e000-7fb38afae000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 134452                     /usr/lib/libibus.so.2.0.0
7fb38afae000-7fb38b1ae000 ---p 00040000 09:02 134452                     /usr/lib/libibus.so.2.0.0
7fb38b1ae000-7fb38b1af000 r--p 00040000 09:02 134452                     /usr/lib/libibus.so.2.0.0
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), doing an "ubuntu-bug gedit" and following the instructions will start that process.

Comment: thanks, but the bug is not really connected with gedit. The same happens with many applications. How can I report this?

Comment: ok I've edited your question to ask that.

Comment: If anybody was interested, now I think the problem is strictly related to VNC connection. Especially after reading this: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49264/gedit-and-gnome-admin-tool-closes-in-vnc-session). So, who do you think a culprit is? Surely not VNC, nor libgtk? Where to report the bug?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **file the bug in Launchpad, using `ubuntu-bug`, against any relevant package.** Filing a good bug, even if it's against the wrong package, is still useful: it's easy for someone better placed to redirect it in to the right one, and much easier than dealing with a bug that doesn't have a stacktrace or other technical information.

As far as which package it should go against:

1. Filing against one application that does show the problem is a good place to start.
2. Choosing the package corresponding to the innermost stack frame that's not really generic like libc would also be reasonable, so (just going off what you show here) `libpixman` could be reasonable.
3. The file dialog for gedit comes from `libgtk2` (or maybe `libgtk3` depending) so that could also be ok.

This stack trace looks truncated so getting the actual right one by reporting with `ubuntu-bug` would be much better.